# Symfony httpClient $response->getInfo() returns empty values

Tags: symfony, curl, symfony-http-client

I'm trying to measure the response duration for some services called from my application.

I just need a simple method and a rough value is good enough, and I thought I could simply use `total_time` from `curl_getinfo`, and  get this value from `$response->getInfo()`, but it is always 0.

Is there some configuration or header that I am missing?

I use

```
if (!empty($headers)) {
   $httpClient = HttpClient::create(['headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
          'accept' =>  'application/json',
   ]]);
} else {
   $httpClient = HttpClient::create();
}

if ($method == 'GET') {
   $response = $httpClient->request($method, $url . $pathParams);
} else {
   $response = $httpClient->request($method, $url, ['body' => json_encode($arguments)]);
}

dd($response->getInfo());
```

and the output contains mostly empty values

```
^ array:44 [
  "response_headers" => []
  "http_code" => 0
  "error" => null
  "canceled" => false
  "http_method" => "POST"
  "user_data" => null
  "start_time" => 1650918719.2348
  "url" => "https://myworkingexample.com"
  "content_type" => null
  "header_size" => 0
  "request_size" => 0
  "filetime" => -1
  "ssl_verify_result" => 0
  "redirect_count" => 0
  "total_time" => 0.0
  "namelookup_time" => 0.0
  "connect_time" => 0.0
  "pretransfer_time" => 0.0
  "size_upload" => 0.0
  "size_download" => 0.0
  "speed_download" => 0.0
  "speed_upload" => 0.0
  "download_content_length" => -1.0
  "upload_content_length" => -1.0
  "starttransfer_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_url" => null
  "primary_ip" => ""
  "certinfo" => []
  "primary_port" => 0
  "local_ip" => ""
  "local_port" => 0
  "http_version" => 0
  "protocol" => 0
  "ssl_verifyresult" => 0
  "scheme" => ""
  "appconnect_time_us" => 0
  "connect_time_us" => 0
  "namelookup_time_us" => 0
  "pretransfer_time_us" => 0
  "redirect_time_us" => 0
  "starttransfer_time_us" => 0
  "total_time_us" => 0
  "debug" => ""
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpClient is "lazy", and will only execute/resolve the request when it's actually needed.

A call to `ResponseInterface::getInfo()` is defined to be non-blocking, and won't execute the request. It will just tell you the *current* state of the request. If you haven't actually executed it, the returned info will be empty, as you are getting.

For `getInfo()` to return meaningful data, you'll need to call first one of the "blocking" methods. E.g.:

- `$response->getContent()`
- `$response->getStatusCode()`
- `$response->getHeaders()`

Any of these can throw an exception, so you may need to deal with that before you are able to call `getInfo()`.